# loop through (char *c, ...)

Tags: c

I'm new to C, and I need to loop through arguments of a routine:

```
void doSmth(char *c, ...) { //how to print all the elements here? }
```

Since I come from Java, this is quite new to me, and I have no idea how to do this in C?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show how you'd call this, and what results you're expecting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because your function declaration is like:

`void doSmth(char *c, ...);`

What you needs is called variable number of argument functions, you can read from : [9.9. Variable numbers of arguments](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/stdarg.html) a good and essay tutorial

Example code with function doSmth() *its 4 steps, read comments*:

```
//Step1: Need necessary header file
#include <stdarg.h>     
void doSmth( char* c, ...){   
    va_list ap;  // vlist variable
    int n;       // number 
    int i;
    float f;     

   //print fix numbers of arguments
   printf(" C: %s", c);

   //Step2: To initialize `ap` using right-most argument that is `c` 
    va_start(ap, c); 

   //Step3: Now access vlist `ap`  elements using va_arg()
     n = va_arg(ap, int); //first value in my list gives number of ele in list 
     while(n--){
       i = va_arg(ap, int);
       f = (float)va_arg(ap, double); //notice type, and typecast  
       printf("\n %d %f \n", i, f);
    }

    //Step4: Now work done, we should reset pointer to NULL
    va_end(ap); 
}
int main(){
    printf("call for 2");
    doSmth("C-string",  2,    3,   6.7f,  5,   5.5f);
        //              ^ this is `n` like count in variable list 
    printf("\ncall for 3");
    doSmth("CC-string", 3,  -12, -12.7f,-14, -14.4f, -67, -0.67f);
         //             ^ this is `n` like count in variable list
    return 1;
}
```

it run like:

```
:~$ ./a.out 
call for 2 C: C-string
 3 6.700000 
 5 5.500000 

call for 3 C: CC-string
 -12 -12.700000 
 -14 -14.400000 
 -67 -0.670000
```

<sub>In C the thing is actually is fixed number of arguments followed by variable numbers of arguments</sub>

Comment: @NikKovac welcome but you should write your question clearly Mr. Joachim Pileborg was trying since you posted question..

Comment: @NikKovac I removed some compiler errors now its in running form, Please find updated code..:) Good Luck