# Compilation error for kernel header file printk.h

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, linux-kernel, header, redhat

I am trying to compile some device driver code using gcc 8.3.1 on redhat8, and run into compilation errors for code statements of the following kind in the included header file `printk.h`:

```
ifdef CONFIG_EARLY_PRINTK
extern asmlinkage __printf(1, 2)
void early_printk(const char *fmt, ...);
#else
static inline __printf(1, 2) __cold
void early_printk(const char *s, ...) { }
#endif
```

For the lines under the `#else` block the compiler flags the following error:

```
Makefile:55: Using kernel headers from /usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-240.15.1.el8_3.x86_64/include
Makefile:112: Setting -DMODVERSIONS for /usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-240.15.1.el8_3.x86_64/include/linux/modversions.h
gcc  -D<driver related flag> -D<driver related flag> -D<driver related flag> -D<driver related flag> -c -o driver_source.o driver_source.c
In file included from /usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-240.15.1.el8_3.x86_64/include/linux/kernel.h:15,
                 from /usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-240.15.1.el8_3.x86_64/include/linux/list.h:9,
                 from /usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-240.15.1.el8_3.x86_64/include/linux/module.h:9,
                 from driver_source.c:41:
/usr/src/kernels/4.18.0-240.15.1.el8_3.x86_64/include/linux/printk.h:145:24: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before numeric constant
 static inline __printf(1, 2) __cold
```

I was searching for similar posts on stack overflow and stumbled on the following:

[what-does-this-generic-function-do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17825588/what-does-this-generic-function-do)

Based on the accepted answer, the code seems to be correct, but I am not sure why the compiler flags this error. I get similar errors in other kernel header files as well.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

TIA

Vinod

Comment: How do you build your device driver? Please, show the **complete** error message: it should include the header and line number, and all other headers involved, till to the source file (`.c`).

Comment: Can you build a simple "hello world" type module?

Comment: I can't mention the source file due to corporate reasons; however I can modify my original post to include all the kernel header files up to printk.h. The driver is built using a Makefile from the vendor.

Comment: In the updated log, I have replaced confidential stuff with the generic "driver"

Comment: Just wanted to add one more thing, the driver source code dates back from 2005 and had been compiled successfully on rhel6

Comment: Obviously you have to forward port it.